# Lebesgue integrable function without compact support.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}, m)$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.  By definition we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f dm < \infty$$

Does $f$ have compact support?  This makes sense, but I don't know if it's true.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but what about $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) dx$ where $f(x)=1/x^2$ if $x \not \in (-1,1)$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x \in (0,1)$?

Comment: No. The integral $e^{-x^2}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $\sqrt{\pi}$ I believe. So it is not even true if $f$ is analytic.

Comment: In addition to the counterexamples already provided, note that you need an absolute value in $\int_\Bbb R \left|f\right| dm < \infty$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Unless I'm mistaken, I think both conditions are equivalent.  By def, $\int f = \int f^+ - \int f^-$ ,but $|f| = f^+ + f^-$

Comment: @user138768 $\int f = \int f^+ - \int f^-$. $\int f$ is undefined if both $\int f^+$ and $\int f^-$ are $\infty$. This is why we check the absolute value.

Comment: @AymanHourieh  Whenever $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, $\int f < \infty$.  This holds always, correct?  So what was incorrect, about what I wrote?  It follows immediately from the definition, which is  : a function is leb. integrable if $\int |f| < \infty$.

Comment: @user138768 I think the criticism is that, strictly speaking, $\int f < \infty$ would allow $\int f = -\infty$, i.e. $\int f^+ \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\int f^- = \infty$, but such an $f$ wouldn't be considered to be in $L^1$.

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Since the Lesbegue integral ignores countable sets, and $\mathbb{R}$ is seperable, you can take any Lesbegue integrable function, define it to be nonzero on some countable dense set and you have a set that's not compactly supported.

Comment: How does that give you a function that's not compactly supported?   The support is the closure of $\{x : f(x) \ne 0\}$.

Comment: Typo, fixed it. Meant nonzero

Comment: You don't really need to requie *dense* - just setting $f(n) = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ should suffice to make $f$ not compactly supported if it was before.

Comment: True, but this is more general (applies to any separable ms domain)

Comment: Also, if you're dealing with lebesgue integrals, you'd usually be more interested in the *essential support*, which is the smallest closed subset $C$ such that $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere *outside* of $C$, i.e. $\mu(f^{-1}(0) \setminus C) = 0$.

Comment: Okay. This means that every equivalence class in $L^1$ has a function without compact support, yet the continuous functions with compact support in $L^1$ are dense in $L^1$.  Wow.